# How to insert into python nested list

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I want to insert an item into a list inside a list. I'm wondering if someone can show me.

```
list5 = [[], [(1,2,3,4), 2, 5]]
print("1. list5", list5)
list5.insert(0, (2,5,6,8))
print("2. list5", list5)

Output:
1. list5 [[], [(1, 2, 3, 4), 2, 5]]
2. list5 [(2, 5, 6, 8), [], [(1, 2, 3, 4), 2, 5]]
```

I want:

```
2. list5 [[(2, 5, 6, 8)], [(1, 2, 3, 4), 2, 5]]
```

A dictionary unfortunately won't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you are trying to insert as the first element of the list, `list5` which is incorrect. You have to access the first element of the list and insert it to that list. This can be done using the following code

```
>>> list5 = [[], [(1,2,3,4), 2, 5]]
>>> print("1. list5", list5)
1. list5 [[], [(1, 2, 3, 4), 2, 5]]
>>> list5[0].insert(0, (2,5,6,8))
>>> print("2. list5", list5)
2. list5 [[(2, 5, 6, 8)], [(1, 2, 3, 4), 2, 5]]
```

Comment: Glad to be of some help to you, twice :P

Comment: Yes, last one was with box = Box().

Comment: Nice to see that you remember me :)

Answer (score 1):

def add_new_item(l1):

```
l1[2][2].append(700)
print(l1)
```

l1 = [10, 20, [300, 400, [5000, 6000], 500], 30, 40]

add_new_item(l1)

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that `insert` creates a *new* item in the list that it is applied to. So

```
>>> list5 = [[], [(1,2,3,4), 2, 5]]
```

creates a list with two elements, the first of which happens to be a list with zero elements:

```
>>> list5[0]
## []
```

If you then call `list5.insert(0, foo)`, what will happen is that `foo` gets pushed into the list at position 0, and everything else gets shoved along (i.e. the elements of the list which had an index of 0 or greater each get their index increased by 1).

What you actually want to do is to insert an element into the empty list at position 0 of `list5`.  So you need to access that list, and then call a method that adds your element. Either

```
>>> list5[0].append( (2,5,6,8) )
```

or

```
>>> list5[0].insert(0, (2,5,6,8) )
```

will do the trick.